# iPhone: How to find string in a complete string

Tags: iphone

How to get the a certain string from a complete string.

For ex: I have a complete string like below.

```
"http://serverurl.com/mediadata/Album.wav";
```

I need to get "Album.wav" from the above string. The name varies with different url string. How to get it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use path components:

```
NSString fileName = [URLstring lastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSScanner probably and scan up to the 4th slash. whats left after the scan would be the string you want.

**Edited**

However as with what Richard said if your url isn't going to change a simple path component will work since NSString parses file paths for you. heres an example.

```
NSArray *urlStrings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://serverurl.com/mediadata/Album.wav",
                                                @"http://serverurl.com/mediadata/NewAlbum.wav",
                                                @"http://serverurl.com/mediadata/OtherAlbum.mp3", nil];

for (NSString *url in urlStrings) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[url lastPathComponent]);
}
```

**Output**

```
2012-04-15 09:01:15.878 NSScanner[6448:f803] Album.wav
2012-04-15 09:01:15.880 NSScanner[6448:f803] NewAlbum.wav
2012-04-15 09:01:15.881 NSScanner[6448:f803] OtherAlbum.mp3
```

Comment: working on a sample. give me just a minute. Also is the only part thats going to change the filename? or will the extension, and url before it change as well?

Comment: What Richard and WhiteTiger are saying is correct. NSScanner is overkill if you're only going to be using simple urls such as the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the NSString class methods, those that begin with rangeOfString:

```
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString;
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask;
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask range:(NSRange)aRange;
- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask range:(NSRange)searchRange locale:(NSLocale *)locale;
```

Comment: with your example you can use the following: - (NSArray *)pathComponents; will return an array containing the elements of the path